# Mongoose: how to define a combination of fields to be unique?

Tags: mongoose

If I had a schema like this:

```js
var person = new Schema({
  firstName:  String,
  lastName: String,
});
```

I'd like to ensure that there is only one document with the same firstName and lastName.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 140, accepted):

You can define a unique compound index using an `index` call on your schema:

```js
person.index({ firstName: 1, lastName: 1}, { unique: true });
```

Comment: @chovy You don't need to drop the collection, but you do need to drop any existing compound index on the fields.

Comment: I did not have an existing compound index. But I was able to add duplicates just fine (repeatedly), even after restarting my app server. It didn't take until I dropped the collection.

Comment: This worked for me on the first try, without having to drop or modify the collection in any other way

Comment: Mongoose makes available a `Model.ensureIndexes([cb])` method which "Sends `ensureIndex` commands to mongo for each index declared in the schema." This may help with the issues of getting the index to stick, though I have read that you should be careful about using the `ensureIndex` command in production

Comment: The index will only be created if the unique requirements are met. 
This explains why @chovy had to drop his collection (could have just delete the duplicates)

Comment: @RonenTeva is there anyway to list the dups?

Comment: @chovy sure, posted it as a new question: [How to list and remove duplicate values using mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252491/how-to-list-duplicate-values-using-mongoose/38252492)

Comment: To determine what duplicates are preventing the index from sticking, you could do:

`Model.on('index', function(err) { console.log(err) });`

Comment: Is this unique only for (firstName+lastName) or is it unique for (lastName+firstName) as well?

Comment: When I use this in model, how to set in route: if (unique compound index) { console.log('unique compound index is set'); } ?

Comment: you can add a name for your index, with a unique index name, it will always work.
```person.index({firstName: 1, lastName: 1}, {name: 'unique_index_name', unique: true})```

Comment: Out of curiosity - what `1` means here?

Comment: @DominikKrzywiecki 1 = ascending, -1 = descending order

Comment: I am using MongoDB Atlas and I had to first drop the collection.

Answer (score 44):

Fun little thing I only recently discovered through experimentation with Mongoose. I have the following schema for example:

```js
const ShapesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true },
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' }
})

ShapesSchema.index({ name: 1, user: 1 }, { unique: true })

mongoose.model('Shapes', ShapesSchema)
```

The idea was to create a compound index that was unique on `name` and `user` together. This way a user could create as many shapes as they wanted as long as each of their shapes had a distinct name. And the inverse was supposed to be true as well - shapes could have the same name as long as they had different users. It didn't work out like that for me.

What I noticed was that aside from the index on `_id`, three other index entries were created. One each for `name`, `user`, and `name_user` all set to be unique. I made a modification to the schema and included `unique: false` to each of the fields I was using for the compound index and suddenly it all worked as expected. What I ended up with was:

```js
const ShapesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, required: true, unique: false },
  user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', unique: false }
})

ShapesSchema.index({ name: 1, user: 1 }, { unique: true })

mongoose.model('Shapes', ShapesSchema)
```

Looking at the indexes that were created as a result I still see the three indexes - `name`, `user`, and `name_user`. But the difference is that the first two are not set to be unique where the last one, the compound, is. Now my use case of multiple distinct shapes per user, or identically named shapes with different users works like a champ.

Comment: This helped me immensely.  I also needed to add `mongoose.connect(uri, { useCreateIndex: true });` per the docs here: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#indexes

Comment: Update (2023)
The behavior reported in the answer above has now been changed. This issue is no longer reproducible with Mongoose 5.10 or any later versions (5.10 is the earliest version I tested with).

It appears that this problem was a bug with Mongoose, which has now been fixed.

Answer (score 3):

defining your schema like this

```
var person = new Schema({
firstName:  String,
lastName: String,
index: true,
unique: true, 

});
```

or

```
person.index({ firstName: 1, lastName: 1}, { unique: true });
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const personSchema = new Schema({ firstName:  String, lastName: String });
const person = mongoose.model('recipients', personSchema);
person.createIndexes();
```

You might need to get rid of all duplicates in the collection or do it the faster and easy way :

> Edit your Code, Drop the Collection and then restart Mongo.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this, but using a unique index should do the trick.

```
db.person.ensureIndex( { "firstname": 1, "lastname": 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

Comment: this is not implemented in mongoose

Comment: for me mongoose did not call ensureIndex so this worked for me thanks

Answer (score -3):

You can define Your Schema like this.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

    const userSchema = new Schema({
      firstName: {
        trim: true,
        type: String,
        required: [true, "firstName is required!"],
        validate(value) {
          if (value.length < 2) {
            throw new Error("firstName is invalid!");
          }
        }
      },
      lastName: {
        trim: true,
        type: String,
        required: [true, "lastName is required!"],
        validate(value) {
          if (value.length < 2) {
            throw new Error("lastName is invalid!");
          }
        }
      },
      username: {
        unique: [true, "Username already available"],
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Username is required"],
        validate(value) {
          if (value.length < 10) {
            throw new Error("Username is invalid!");
          }
        }
      },
      mobile: {
        unique: [true, "Mobile Number alraedy available"],
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Mobile Number is required"],
        validate(value) {
          if (value.length !== 10) {
            throw new Error("Mobile Number is invalid!");
          }
        }
      },
      password: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, "Password is required"],
        validate(value) {
          if (value.length < 8) {
            throw new Error("Password is invalid!");
          }
        }
      },
      gender: {
        type: String
      },
      dob: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now()
      },
      address: {
        street: {
          type: String
        },
        city: {
          trim: true,
          type: String
        },
        pin: {
          trim: true,
          type: Number,
          validate(value) {
            if (!(value >= 100000 && value <= 999999)) {
              throw new Error("Pin is invalid!");
            }
          }
        }
      }
      date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
    });
```

Comment: How exactly is this making the pair `firstName, lastName` unique?