# How can I set composite primary key in mongodb through mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to set primary key for two fields in a collection in `mongodb` through `mongoose`. I know to set composite primary key in `mongodb` as

```
db.yourcollection.ensureIndex( { fieldname1: 1, fieldname2: 1 }, { unique: true } )
```

but am using `mongoose` to handle `mongodb` I don't know how to set composite primary key from `mongoose`

**update**

I used `mySchema.index({ ColorScaleID: 1, UserName: 1}, { unique: true });`
see my code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')

var uristring ='mongodb://localhost/fresh';
var mongoOptions = { db: { safe: true } };

// Connect to Database
mongoose.connect(uristring, mongoOptions, function (err, res) {
    if (err) {
        console.log ('ERROR connecting to: remote' + uristring + '. ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log ('Successfully connected to: remote' + uristring);
    }
});
var mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
        ColorScaleID:String,
        UserName:String,
        Range1:Number,
    })
mySchema.index({ ColorScaleID: 1, UserName: 1}, { unique: true });
var freshtime= mongoose.model("FreshTimeColorScaleInfo",mySchema)
var myVar = new freshtime({
        ColorScaleID:'red',
        UserName:'tab',
        Range1:10
    })
myVar.save()
mongoose.connection.close();
```

When I execute this code for first time I see a line `{"_id":...,ColorScaleID:'red',UserName:'tab',Range1:10 }` in mongodb's fresh database. When I execute the same code for second time I see two same lines.

```
{"_id":...,ColorScaleID:'red',UserName:'tab',Range1:10 }
{"_id":...,ColorScaleID:'red',UserName:'tab',Range1:10 }
```

If `composite primary key` worked then it shouldn't allow me to insert same data for second time. what would be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Mongoose: how to define a combination of fields to be unique?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16061744/mongoose-how-to-define-a-combination-of-fields-to-be-unique)

Comment: @JohnnyHK I have updated my question, can you have a look at it again.

Comment: I achieved same functionality with mongodb's query in mongodb shell is `db.person.ensureIndex({ ColorScaleID: 1, UserName: 1}, { unique: true })`, but not with mongoose `mySchema.index({ ColorScaleID: 1, UserName: 1}, { unique: true })`.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - I don't think that it's a duplicate as he's got the definition right it's just not working for him.

Comment: @Guy - It was at the time, but it's been updated since then.

Comment: @JohnnyHK - good call in getting the question updated to make it unique!

Answer (score 1):

The way that you have defined your schema is correct and will work. What you are probably experiencing is that the database has already been created and that collection probably already exists even though it might be empty. Mongoose won't retro fit the index.

As an experiment, set your database to a DB that does not exist. e.g.:

```
var uristring ='mongodb://localhost/randomname';
```

and then try running those two lines against this database and see if you can still insert those two documents.

Then compare the contents of the "system.indexes" collection in each of those collections. You should see that the randomname db has the composite index correctly set.

Comment: this still isn't working for me on new data. How do I delete the collection, and this is a bit concerning if i want to add a key later, its completely ignored?

Answer (score 0):

As everybody mentioned, you got to use index method of a Schema to set composite unique key.
But this isn't enough, try restarting MongoDB after that.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this in your mongoose schema model,

```
const AppSchema1 = new Schema({
  _id         :{appId:String, name:String},
  name        : String
});
```